# One or more of your projects encountered errors when linking when migrating from fabric to firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am trying to migrating my iOS project Crashlytics from Fabric to Firebase. When I try to link my project in fabric to Firebase, I get error like below. If I click retry linking, nothing happens. 
Can anybody help what can I do?

[image]

Comment: Hi Seung, I am also facing the same problem. But I am facing it only for two iOS Apps. I have successfully migrated a few Android and iOS Apps. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your app's name in Fabric console to something simple (only small latin letters, no dashes, etc.)